# Comparing user input with string and deciding weather or not it is true

Tags: python, string, input, boolean

I'm totally new to programming and the answer might be obvious but here is my problem: I'm trying to write a program that is like an adventure book. I want the program to take user input, compare it with a list of possible answers and then continue with the story (for example: "You get to the first location, what do you do?" based on the previously made list the player could either climb the tree or steal the cat or whatever). This doesn't work too well as it always gives me the option under else:

```
rain = input("Does it rain? ")
is_raining = False

if rain.islower() == "yes":
    is_raining = True
    print(is_raining)

if is_raining == True:
    print("Take an umbrella")
else:
    print("Shorts are fine")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you used the method `rain.islower()` you are only testing if the cases are low. For what you need you have to use `rain.lower()` to compare with `'yes'`.